# Self test is not working for me

Tags: google-schemas

I have tested action script under the article "Apps Script Quickstart". 
After the script runs, check my inbox for an email sent from myself with a Go-To Action button, but i can't see the Action button on inbox.

Can anyone help me.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your script, so I'm not sure why you're not seeing the action button.

You also have the option of using the following Gmail Schemas Tester below with your Gmail account:

http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/

On the bottom left, you can select the action you'd like to test. For example, I selected "Go-to action" and the sample was sent to my Gmail.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks. i've tested with two email adress. One is a@gmail.com and Two is a@sendin.com. (Here "a" is example.) but i can see only with a@gmail.com. Why can't see with two email?

Comment: @GaunYun it will only work with your Gmail account. If your email (a@sendin.com) is not a Google Apps domain, you will have to be whitelisted in order to use a non Gmail account. You can find the registration guidelines and submission form at the following link (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).